# Why is popover title function called twice

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to load the title for my popover dynamically. It works fine but the function to load is called twice every time. Why is this?

```
<body> <a href="#" id="button", class="btn btn-primary">Add Icon</a> </body>

$("#button").popover({
html: true,
title: popoverTitle,
content: "Popover content",
});
function popoverTitle() {
console.log("Loading title");  // outputs twice every time
return "Popover Title";
};
```

Code on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unw1mcj9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is not with your code. It comes from bootstrap itself. See this link: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12563